# What does Annie tell Owen that scares him?

Tags: being-human

In Season 1 episode 5, Annie whispers something to her husband who murdered her. This causes him to run in panic.

[image]

Is it ever found out exactly what it is she said? Or was she just making something up to scare Owen?

Comment: We don't know. [That's the joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouDoNOTWantToKnow)

Comment: Wait... so this is _not_ a question about Star Wars?!?!?!

Comment: @RedCaio Why you even supposed that?

Comment: @ankitsharma - Little orphan Annie is a major character in the Star Wars films.

Comment: @AnkitSharma "What does Annie (Skywalker) tell (uncle) Owen (Lars) that scares him?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full quote is

> **Annie:** ... *we’ve got your scent now. We can find you at the edge of
>   the earth. And create unimaginable tortures. And now I’m going to tell
>   you the very worst thing in the world. Something only the dead know.*
>   {she whispers in his ear.}
>
> **Owen:** *That’s not true!*
>
> **Annie:** ***I saw it...***

Assuming she's not just making something up to scare him, I think we can be reasonably certain that she told him something about the door process (perhaps  that Hell is very real and that when he dies, he's going to be dragged there kicking and screaming?). Beyond that, this is an example of the trope "[You do NOT want to know](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/YouDoNOTWantToKnow)" both in and out of universe.